# problem in get data from database using axios in react and laravel in my project

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, axios

I use Axios in react code and laravel in the backend and when I send a request to get all data from table with Axios code and index method in controller in laravel I get status equal = 200 and in data I get code exists in page.blade.php:

1. *{data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html >\n <head>\n <meta c…\n \n \n </body>\n</html>\n\n\n', status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}*

   1. **config**: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: *ƒ*, …}
   2. **data**: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html >\n <head>\n <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n <link ..."
   3. **headers**: {cache-control: 'no-cache, private', connection: 'close', content-type: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', date: 'Thu, 09 Feb 2023 10:09:00 GMT, Thu, 09 Feb 2023 10:09:00 GMT', host: 'localhost:8000', …}
   4. **request**: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
   5. **status**: 200
   6. **statusText**: "OK"
   7. [[Prototype]]: Object

      ```
      import React, { useState } from "react";
      import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
      import axios from "axios";
      import './login.css'

      export default function Login(){
          const [account,setAccount]=useState({
              mail:"",
              password:"",
              surname:"",
              name:""
          })
          e.preventDefault()
              const res =await axios.get("/login").then((result)=>{
                   console.log(result)
              })
              console.log(res)
          }
          return(
              <div className="containerGlobal">
                  <div className="containerLogin">
                      <h3 className="titleLogin">Tractafric CFC</h3>
                      <form onSubmit={(e)=>checkAccount(e)}>
                          <div className="input-group mb-3">
                              <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email" name="email" value={account.mail} onChange={(e)=>setAccount({...account,mail:e.target.value})}/>
                          </div>
                          <div className="input-group mb-3">
                              <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">**</span>
                              <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Password"  name="password"  value={account.password} onChange={(e)=>setAccount({...account,password:e.target.value})}/>
                          </div>
                          <div className="input-group mb-3">
                              <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email" name="name" value={account.name} onChange={(e)=>setAccount({...account,name:e.target.value})}/>
                          </div>
                          <div className="input-group mb-3">
                              <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">**</span>
                              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Password"  name="surname"  value={account.surname} onChange={(e)=>setAccount({...account,surname:e.target.value})}/>
                          </div>
                          <div className="containerBtnLogin">
                              <button className="loginBtn"  type="submit"  ><i className="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i> Login </button>
                              <button className="loginBtn" onClick={(e)=>getAll(e)}><i className="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i> Load </button>
                              <Link to="/">Reset password</Link>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
          );
      }
      ```

````
      
      **This is react code** 
      
      and in controller 
      ```
      public function index()
          {
              $handlers=Handler::find(2);
              return response()->json(['status'=> 200,'handlers'=>$handlers]);
          }
      
      ```
````

Comment: Your return text/html as 'data' from your php-controller. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you want to get data with Axios, you should set your response in laravel as json, and Axios header should be Accept: application/json